# How to disable Clipboard in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, gtk, clipboard, clipboard-manager

Is there a way to disable the clipboard completely?
The goal is to block the usage of right Click Copy / Paste along with Ctrl+c / Ctrl+v in a  restricted desktop environment.

Searched for a quite a bit and couldn't find any definitive answer. Thanks in advance for any  pointers or help.

Comment: Probably you will need to edit source code of core graphical system libraries (GTK, QT) and recompile the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Honestly, I am not expert enough to edit the core libraries. I was hoping for simpler solutions like gcof / dconf editing. If there is no way to get this done, thinking of something (script or package) that can intercept clipboard events and empty the clipboard instantly.

Comment: If you do not want to disable the clipboard, but just prevent the hotkeys for copy/paste to stop working, then that will be easier. However, then you are not blocking access through the menus or other means.

Comment: Is this for your own computer or are you deploying it to someone else's computer?

Comment: This is for deploying locked down devices across an organization. Not my own computer.